# Keycloak only returning HS256 token

Tags: keycloak

Im using Keycloak 19 to authenticate my frontend and it actually works fine. I receive a JWT token which is kept in a serviceworker via react-oidc.

The only problem im facing that i expect a rsa256 token however the token i receive is hs256. Even if i disable hs256 or anything else im still not receiving the token.

The reason why i want a rsa token is that it is easier to sign the token in my apis without the interconnected traffic to validate anything. If someone explains me a good reason why not it could also be fine but this is atleast the idea.

Front -> keycloak -> frontend (jwt token)
Frontend -> app api (validate with public) -> frontend

Did i miss anything that it keeps going wrong?

Pim

Comment: I try to hook up between Keycloak and react-oidc.
This configuration seems to be a Key.
https://github.com/AxaGuilDEv/react-oidc/blob/master/packages/react/public/OidcTrustedDomains.js
How to setup this config for local Keycloak?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The domain of keycloak is in the list so that should be fine. The thing is that after authentication the cookie "KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY" is of type HS256 and not RS256.

Comment: I understood your token header's algorithm is  returned "HS256" instead of "RS256". My question how to reproduce your problem. Upper question is how to set a configuration of 'react-oidc' for local Keycloak. I want to reproduce your token problem.